# Competition prep question: 168 ways to stitch patches of four colors into 4 x 4 grid so that no patch touch another of the same color

Tags: combinatorics

I'm helping the high school son of a friend prepare for a maths competition.

This question has me stumped.

[image]
The text of the puzzle is as follows:

> My grandson makes wall hangings by stitching together 16 square patches of fabric into a 4 x 4 grid. I asked him to use patches of red, blue, green, and yellow, but to ensure that no patch touches another of the same colour, not even diagonally.
> The picture shows an attempt which fails only because two yellow patches touch diagonally.
> In how many different ways can my grandson choose to arrange the coloured patches correctly?

The pictures shows the wall hanging as follows:

> row 1: G B R Y
> row 2: R Y G B
> row 3: G B Y R
> row 4: Y R G B

The answer is $168$, something I've confirmed by writing a program that brute force checked every option.

How does one find the $168$ otherwise?

For instance: The top left $2 \times 2$ sub grid has $4!$ options. For each one of those permutations, how does one arrive at the fact that the remaining twelve squares in the grid have $168/4! = 7$ options?

Comment: In fact, _every_ $2\times 2$ square has to have all four colours. Does it help that the top right $2\times 2$ square only has four options, as its columns must be, in your picture, $\begin{bmatrix}G\\R\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}R\\G\end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix}B\\Y\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}Y\\B\end{bmatrix}$. Similarly there are four options for the lower left $2\times 2$ square. That is $16$ options in total, and each either uniquely determines the entire lower right $2\times 2$ square ($7$ of them), or ends up in contradiction ($9$ of them).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Suppose the middle four squares have the pattern
$$ \begin{array}{cccc} *&*&*&*\\*&B&G&* \\ *&R&Y&* \\*&*&*&*\end{array}$$.
The middle two rows can now be completed in four ways:
$$\begin{array} {cccc}  
\begin{array}{cccc} *&*&*&*\\G&B&G&B\\Y&R&Y&R\\*&*&*&* \end{array} \hspace{.6in}
\begin{array}{cccc} *&*&*&*\\G&B&G&R\\Y&R&Y&B\\*&*&*&* \end{array} \hspace{.6in}
\begin{array}{cccc} *&*&*&*\\Y&B&G&B\\G&R&Y&R\\*&*&*&* \end{array} \hspace{.6in}
\begin{array}{cccc} *&*&*&*\\Y&B&G&R\\G&R&Y&B\\*&*&*&* \end{array}
\end{array}$$
It is not difficult to verify that the first case can be completed in four ways; and each of the last three cases can be completed in one way.  So there are seven ways to complete the quilt given the initial choice of the central square colorings.

But also the central square colors can be freely permuted, giving the answer of $7\cdot 24=168$ possible quilt patterns.

Comment: This is the kind of parsimonious solution I was looking for. Thank you.